# Get an array of all columns starting with the same characters.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

This is quite difficult to explain in the title, so I'll do my best here. Basically I have a column in a MySQL products table that contains rows like:

```
FEL10
FEL20
FEL30
PRO05
PRO07
PRO08
VAI12
VAI13
VAI14
```

These are the categories ("FEL","PRO","VAI") and a identification number of my products ("10", "20" and so on). I need an SQL select query that creates me a textual array like:

```
FEL*
PRO*
VAI*
```

With this array I need to create a listbox, that allows me to choose a category (regardless of the identification number). Once I choose a category, let's say PRO*, I will need to do the reverse action: print all the products info related to PRO05, PRO07 and PRO08.

How do you think you can achieve this? I have been trying using the DISTINCT statement but I need to filter only the first characters, otherwise it will be useless. I also tried the SUBSTRING() and LEFT() functions, but they seem not to be working (I get an SQL Syntax error).

--
Thanks for your help as always

Comment: Can you show how you are trying and post details for *i get an SQL Syntax error* [**this fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21734/1) shows no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL `LIKE` to the resque:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE 'FEL%';
```

This way you have to add all cases using `OR`.

Alternative - `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col1 REGEXP '(FEL|PRO|VAI).*'
```

Then it's just a matter of writing proper regex.

I would use extra col to group your items - to avoid such selecting altogether (which should be quite expensive on bigger dataset).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: Thanks but this solution will give me only specific results. I have to assume I won't know all the category codes and I need a generic solution.

Comment: How does that answer the question? It does not show how to get the list of three-letter codes. And it shows how to select products for *various* categories in one go, where the question was actually how to select the products for *one* category.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with?

```
SELECT distinct left(col, 3) as category FROM `table1`
```

Comment: Probably there is nothing wrong at all with that, but maybe category names can have lengths that differ from 3 (which was not explicitly mentioned in the question :))

Comment: Exactly, sorry for not specifiyng that :) The thing is going harder than I tought!

Comment: In that case you have to specify exactly how you separate the category code from the rest of the product id, or all our guesses are probably going to fail...

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of the 3-letter codes use:

```
select distinct left(combicode, 3)
from mytable;
```

When a user selects one of the values use this to get all matching entries:

```
select * 
from mytable
where combicode like concat(@category, '%');
```

(Aside from that: It's a bad idea to have concatenated values in one column. Why not have one column for the category and another for the product code? Then there would be no problem at all.)